# XPath expression to extract weblinks from a chinese search (baidu.com)

Tags: r, xpath

Does anyone know of an XPath expression which will allow me to extract all the search results returned from baidu.com?

For example, in R, I would usually do something like this this:

```
# load libraries    
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

# get webpage
doc <- getURL("http://www.baidu.com/s?rn=100&bs=chivas+regal&f=8&wd=chivas+regal")

# html structure
html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternalNodes = TRUE, error=function(...){})

# use xpath expression to get links
nodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//a[@href]")
```

However this only gets about 10 links, when I should have around 100. So I think this means there is something about the baidu html structure which is not clear to me.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Using [Tidy](http://valet.htmlhelp.com/tidy/) and adding namespace binding to the XPath expression, it works as expected. The error might be in your HTML parser or XPath engine. Retagging accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If Xpath is not an absolute requirement try an approach based on regular expressions. The following assumes all links start with http:// and are in double quotes.  It uses `strapply` to match the indicated regular expression and extract out the back reference, i.e. the part within parentheses.

```
URL <- "http://www.baidu.com/s?rn=100&bs=chivas+regal&f=8&wd=chivas+regal"
Lines <- readLines(URL)
library(gsubfn)
links <- strapply(Lines, '"(http://[^"]*)"', simplify = c)
```